# Count() and left join problem

Tags: sql, mysql, count, left-join

I'm having a problem with the a query which displays a list of shops with the number of products associated with it. I've been playing around with left joins etc for quite a while now but to no avail. The tables have the following structures:

Shops table containing columns: `id`, `name`

Products table containing columns: `id`, `name`, `status`, `shop`

The query is as follows:

```
select s.name
       , p.name
       , count(p.id) 
from   Product as p 
       left join Shop as s on p.shop=s.id
where  p.status <> '8796107276379'
group by 
       s.id
```

I'm not getting the shops which have 0 products. How can I achieve this please?

The underlying database is MySQL.

Thanks! 
Krt_Malta

Comment: try replace right join , instead left

Comment: No, it doesn't work out. I get the following error: cannot find (visible) type for alias s within [p:product, s right:Shop]. (It's a proprietary query langauge)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need SHOP on the LEFT side, since the right side is the one that may not have data, in this case PRODUCT.

Not only that, you need the WHERE condition as a LEFT-JOIN ON condition, so that it joins to products on the status condition and just discounts the product (while keeping shop) even if the status is not desired.

```
select s.name
       , p.name
       , count(p.id) 
from   Shop as s
       left join Product as p on p.shop=s.id AND p.status <> '8796107276379'
group by 
       s.id, p.name
```

Comment: I found many aproxes online. This is the best solution. Thank you for asking and answering.

Answer (score 1):

```
select s.name
       , p.name
       , count(p.id) 
from   Shop as s 
       left join Product as p on s.id=p.shop
where  p.status <> '8796107276379'
group by 
       s.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `OR p.status IS NULL` to your where clause.

```
select s.name, p.name, count(p.id) 
from Shop s 
left join Product p on p.shop = s.id
where (p.status <> '8796107276379' OR p.status IS NULL) 
group by s.name, p.name
```

Comment: Nope didn't work. Why do you think is should work with p.status IS NULL?

Comment: You said your query isn't returning shops without any products. Without "OR p.status IS NULL", your where clause will indeed exclude all such cases, because comparison "NULL <> '8796107276379'" is never true. NULL is not equal with anything (even another NULL), nor is it not equal with anything.

Answer (score 0):

I suffered this gotcha too and though I am not entirely sure why, placing the predicate on the jojn itself rather than the actual main query is how to solve it.

I actually documented the whole thing, before reading this. I used a simple example with two two small tables, it explains I hope the difference, maybe it will help

http://simpleritsolutions.com/sql/left/join/problems

Comment: Instead of leaving a link, could you post the relevant material from the article too? Otherwise the link could become a victim of link rot