# SQL - placing condition in where clause

Tags: sql, count, group-by, left-join, where-clause

Earlier on today I asked this question at SO: [Count() and left join problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4983544/count-and-left-join-problem)

As indicated, the correct query for my problem is:

```
select s.name
       , p.name
       , count(p.id) 
from   Shop as s
       left join Product as p on p.shop=s.id AND p.status <> '8796107276379'
group by 
       s.id, p.name
```

We are using a proprietary framework which allows us to add restrictions to queries running on the system. I am quite sure that it is being achieved through a `where` clause being appended at the end of the queries.

The problem is can I translate the above query in such a manner that `p.status <> '8796107276379'` is in a `where` clause so that I could add this as a restriction?

The other answers at [Count() and left join problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4983544/count-and-left-join-problem) all put the condition in the `where` clause but none of them worked.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Krt_Malta

Comment: A WHERE clause cannot be appended after a GROUP BY clause. Please explain precisely which part of the query is generated by the framework and which part of the query you get to control.

Answer (score 2):

```
select s.name
       , p.name
       , count(p.id) 
from   Shop as s
       left join Product as p on p.shop=s.id
where
       p.shop is null or p.status <> '8796107276379'
group by 
       s.id, p.name
```

This will work on Oracle and MySQL, but it might fail on SQL Server (not sure).

Comment: +1, should work. it would be great if you would explain why you test for null (you don't need to explain it to me so).

Answer (score 1):

Sure... (for SQL Server)

```
select s.name
       , p.name
       , count(p.id) 
from   Shop as s
       left join Product as p on p.shop=s.id 
where IsNull(p.status,'') <> '8796107276379'
group by 
       s.id, p.name
```